# How to give more space to Ubuntu in triple boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have 3 Operating Systems on my machine - Windows, Kali and Ubuntu. I wish to increase the space given to Ubuntu from Windows. I'm not sure how to proceed in this case.

Here are my partitions as viewed through Ubuntu

[HDD Partitions - Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhay.jpg)

In the above image:

```
sda3 - Windows (C Drive)
sda4 - swap
sda5 - Ubuntu
sda7 - Windows (D Drive - Recovery)
sda8 - Kali
```

I wish to allocate space from sda3 (C Drive) to sda5 (Ubuntu).

Comment: Would use Windows partition tools to shrink window partition first.  Can then use gparted as stated in above link.  If using 18.04 or 20.04, can probably delete swap partition(needs to be moved before adding space to ubuntu anyway).  Leave windows with at least 20% or more free space after shrinking.

Comment: Might have problems booting Ubuntu after since adding space to left(front) of Ubuntu's partition.  Hopefully will just need to update grub.

Comment: The swap space comes in between. How do I take care of that?

Comment: Gparted can delete or move swap out of way.  Moving/changing partitions is not always safe for data even if everything works.  Should backup important data first.  Quite a few posts about people losing data when working on partitions.  The easy way would be shrink windows, delete swap and ubuntu and then re-install ubuntu in new partition, if data is backup.